# max and min with NaN in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Why is it that the max of NaN and a number is NaN, but the min of NaN and a number is the number? This seems to be at odds with a few other languages I have tried:

In Haskell:

```
max (0/0) 1 -- NaN
min (0/0) 1 -- 1.0
```

In Python

```
>>> max(float("nan"),1) #nan
>>> min(float("nan"),1) #nan
```

In JavaScript

```
> Math.max(0/0,1) //NaN
> Math.min(0/0,1) //NaN
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure, but I have a feeling it might have something to do with the fact that `/` applies to `Fractional` values rather than `Integral`. If you were to try dividing using `div` as 0 `div` 0, you would get an error.

Comment: @shree.pat18 Isn't NaN a floating point thing though? I wouldn't think it would apply to integral types in that case.

Comment: @DavidYoung Yes, I agree. Interestingly, `1/0` returns `Infinity`, so I'm not sure what happens to `0/0` - is it treated as infinity but shown as `NaN`, or if `max/min` are defaulted when it is one of the arguments.

Comment: [This thread](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2011-May/thread.html#91859) might give some insights.

Comment: From the same thread, see [this](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2011-May/091865.html) message and [this](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2011-May/091866.html).

Comment: Another related good read: [Making something out of nothing (or, why None is better than NaN and NULL)](https://blogs.janestreet.com/making-something-out-of-nothing-or-why-none-is-better-than-nan-and-null/)

Comment: @shree.pat18 0/0 is undefined, not infinity, it can be anything.

Comment: @PieterB: IEEE 754 defines `0/0` as `NaN`; it's not undefined (in conforming languages).  While Haskell doesn't entirely conform to the spec, it does incorporate this aspect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Haskell report specifies that `(min x y, max x y)` will return either `(x, y)` or `(y, x)`.  This is a nice property, but hard to reconcile with a symmetric treatment of NaN.

It's also worth mentioning that this is exactly the same asymmetry as the SSE2 instructions `MINSD` and `MAXSD` exhibit, i.e., Haskell `min` (for `Double`) can be implemented by `MINSD` and `max` by `MAXSD`.

Answer (score 8):

Not quite, `min 1.0 (0/0)` will return NaN, for instance.

This is because any comparison with NaN is defined to return false, and by the definiton of min and max below :

```
max x y 
     | x <= y    =  y
     | otherwise =  x
min x y
     | x <= y    =  x
     | otherwise =  y
```

min and max with NaN will return second and first argument, respectively.

Comment: So it's a minor bug in the definition of `min` and `max` (namely, the assumption that not `<=` must be `>`)?

Comment: IEEE 754:2008 §5.3.1 specifies that `min` and `max` with NaN ignores the NaN and returns the number. If Haskell claims to follow the standard floating-point behavior, this is a bug.

Comment: does the standard say anything about >,<,== ? Because I think the definition of `min`/`max` is quite reasonable for [total orders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order))

Comment: @CarstenKönig IEEE 754 defines pretty much everything, i.e. a superset of features that few languages or computers implement fully. NaNs cannot be ordered relative to numbers, so if you mean `min` and `max` behave well modulo NaNs, then I guess that's right but it's ignoring the question.

Comment: it was not meant as a answer to the question - I am not familiar with the specs - I'm just saying that from a mathemtical standpoint the definition of min and max is fine. Of course you cannot order NaN (if you include NaN there are many math. properties you throw out) - I just wanted to know if maybe the specs are a bit misleading or even self-contratictory in a sens - so never mind

Comment: @Potatoswatter Haskell does **not** claim to conform to IEEE 754. For example, in the [Haskell 98 Report](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/basic.html) it says: "*The default floating point operations defined by the Haskell Prelude **do not conform** to current language independent arithmetic (LIA) standards.* These standards require considerably more complexity in the numeric structure and have thus been relegated to a library. Some, but not all, aspects of the IEEE floating point standard have been accounted for in Prelude class `RealFloat`."

Answer (score 7):

I'm not a Haskell programmer, but it appears that the floating-point functions are called `fmin` and `fmax`. For whatever reason, the generic functions applied to floating-point types do not follow standard numeric behavior.

`fmin` and `fmax` comply with IEEE 754:2008 §5.3.1:

> **minNum(x, y)** is the canonicalized number *x* if *x < y*, *y* if *y < x*, the canonicalized number if one operand is a number and the other a quiet NaN.

Note that this behavior is opposite JavaScript. Do not do as JavaScript does ;v) .

Comment: The `Ord` class would need to have `min` and `max` as _methods_ to conform with IEEE754 here. But since IEEE754 itself sort of violates more general understanding of how comparisons should behave, it's IMO fine that Haskell hasn't done this and only provides `fmin` and `fmax` for conformance with that standard.

Comment: One could argue that "expected" `NaN` behaviour does not follow standard `Ord` rules :-)